# Display the days of the week in different languages, depending on an option tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to display in HTML, the days of the week, in different languages, depending on the chosen language option, then press the "Compute" button, should display the days, to the right, inside the label tag. But it's not all exactly going according to plan...

Looked it up for quite a while on the Internet, came up with a few things that helped me, but not exactly 100%...

```
<form style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
    <label>Select language:</label>
    <select class="lang">
       <option value="en">En</option>
       <option value="ro">Ro</option>
       <option value="fr">Fr</option>
    </select>
    <label class="showDays"></label>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onClick="displayLang()">Compute</button>
    <button type="reset" onClick="resetLang()">Reset</button>
</form>



window.displayLang = function()  {

    let date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
    let days = date.getDay();

    let week = [];

    let lang = document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0].value;
    let allDays = document.getElementsByClassName("showDays");

    if(lang[0].value = "en")    {

        week.push(days);

        allDays[0].innerHTML = week;

    }

    if(lang[0].value = "ro")  {

        week.splice(0, 0, "Luni", "Marti", "Miercuri", "Joi", "Vineri", "Sambata", "Duminica");

        allDays[0].innerHTML = week;

    }

    if(lang[0].value = "fr")    {

        week.splice(0, 0, "Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi", "Dimanche");

        allDays[0].innerHTML = week;

    }

}

window.resetLang = function()    {
    document.getElementsByClassName("showDays")[0].innerHTML = "";
}
```

Obviously, if I choose "En" option, the days are supposed to display in English, if I choose "Ro" option, the days should display in Romanian, if I choose "Fr" option, the days are supposed to display in French. Instead what I`m getting now is: *Lundi,Mardi,Mercredi,Jeudi,Vendredi,Samedi,Dimanche,Luni,Marti,Miercuri,Joi,Vineri,Sambata,Duminica,3* /////
I just don't understand where the "3" comes from... I'm not after numbers here! Also apparently I could solve this problem using a switch case in JavaScript... I just don't know how I could do that...

Comment: `let days = date.getDay();` will set `days` to a number hence why you have that `3` in your output

Comment: @messerbill How could I display the days of the week in the English language using the: let days = date.getDay(); method, or any other JavaScript built in methods??

Comment: have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date but i recommend you to make use of `moment.js` which is a much better library for the Date handlings than the native `Date API`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must use double equals `==` instead of one `=` in the conditional `if`.
2. You need also to add `else` statement.
3. You need to change `lang[0].value` to `lang` instead.

```js
window.displayLang = function() {
  let date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
  let days = date.getDay();
  let week = [];
  let lang = document.getElementsByClassName("lang")[0].value;
  let allDays = document.getElementsByClassName("showDays");

  if (lang == "en") {
    week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"].join(', ');
    allDays[0].innerHTML = week;
  } else if (lang == "ro") {
    week= ["Luni", "Marti", "Miercuri", "Joi", "Vineri", "Sambata", "Duminica"].join(', ');
    allDays[0].innerHTML = week;
  } else if (lang == "fr") {
    week = ["Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi", "Dimanche"].join(', ');
    allDays[0].innerHTML = week;
  }
}

window.resetLang = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("showDays")[0].innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
  <label>Select language:</label>
  <select class="lang">
    <option value="en">En</option>
    <option value="ro">Ro</option>
    <option value="fr">Fr</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <label class="showDays"></label>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onClick="displayLang()">Compute</button>
  <button type="reset" onClick="resetLang()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Well, it's working, as intended... but instead of the days in English, I'm just getting "3"... I thought that: let date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
  let days = date.getDay();    was supposed to display: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday... or atleast: Mo, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun... :(

Comment: _... I thought that: let date = new Date(); date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7); let days = date.getDay(); was supposed to display: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday... or atleast: Mo, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun... :(_  **Why you think so ?!! The `getDay()` method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date.**

Comment: How do I add one space bar, after each element inside an Array?? Like: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday instead of: Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday.

Comment: Glad I could help.